# Dapper doesn't read values from base-type fields

Tags: c#, sqlite, dapper

Base type:

```cs
public class TreeRecord
{
    public long id;
    public long? parent_id;
}
```

Record type:

```cs
public class TestRecord : TreeRecord
{
    public string name;
}
```

Using Dapper to inset will fail, because it can't find the values. I suspect that is because some of the fields are from the base type.

```cs
public long Add(T record, bool returnIndex = false)
{
    var query =
        $"INSERT INTO {TableName} ({string.Join(", ", _fields)}, parent_id) " +
        $"VALUES (@{string.Join(", @", _fields)}, @parent_id);";

    // Seems like Dapper won't flatten this type hierachy.
    _connection.Execute(query, record);
}
```

I'm working in a generic container, where `T` inherits from TR and "extends" the fields. Because of this, I can't simply provide a flattened `new ...` construct for the value parameters for Dapper. `_fields` are non-base fields in `T`, in this case just `name` from `TestRecord`.

The exception thrown is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Must add values for the following parameters: @name, @parent_id
```

even though both are set (p_id to null, name to Books) (inside Dapper's `Execute`):

[image]

Is it a flattening issue? IMO, because all fields on a `TestRecord`, including the base fields, can be accessed by `var.field`, Dapper should be able to use it.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree that this is a bug; github is your friend there.

Comment: @MarcGravell Not again :/... Issue is already submitted. https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/923 Code to repro is the same repo you already have, but the other branch. I don't really have time now to add more details. It's not urgent either.

Comment: fair enough :) ta

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're seeing here is because ultimately Dapper is looking for *properties* and not fields. Underneath the covers, it's calling `typeof(RecordType).GetProperties();` and enumerating them for the dynamic parameter generation.

If you change your types to:

```cs
public class TreeRecord
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public long? parent_id { get; set; }
}

public class TestRecord : TreeRecord
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

...then you should see it working, on base or inherited types.